# Using Tuple for passing multiple models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view includes login and registration form.

*LoginAndRegister.cshtml file:*

```
    @model Tuple<Models.LoginViewModel, Models.RegisterViewModel>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
    {
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
         @Html.ValidationSummary(false)
         // Form Login here

    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
    {
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
         @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

        // Form Register here

    }
```

AccountController file:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register([Bind(Prefix = "Item2")] RegisterViewModel model)
    {
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
            // enter code here     
         }

         // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
         var tupleModel = new Tuple<LoginViewModel, RegisterViewModel>(null, model);
         return View("LoginAndRegister", tupleModel);
         }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login([Bind(Prefix = "Item1")] LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
         var tupleModel = new Tuple<LoginViewModel, RegisterViewModel>(model, null);

         if (!ModelState.IsValid)
         {
               return View("LoginAndRegister", tupleModel);
         }

     }
```

I have 2 question, if you guys don't mind could you help me?

1. When I pass model (just one item of tuple) from controller to View, i have to change it to Tuple<> type and pass 1 value is null. Does this way is correct？ It's working for me but I afraid that my way isn't correct.
2. And then, when model is invalid (example: values's input in to Login form is invalid), error messages will bind into @Html.ValidationSummary(false). But it's showed in 2 places (register and login form). How to resolve this issue?
   https://gyazo.com/e9146059a6a098ee787565222d8dc744

Thanks for kind helping

Comment: Seems like you're trying to shoehorn something through the model binder.  Why not just make a model that contains all the information you need, and pass that in?

Comment: Yes either make a large ViewModel containing all properties - or make a new ViewModel that contains a LoginViewModel & a RegisterViewModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Login and register are two different models. You can get around using Tuples in asp.net with the html helpers. Using a tuple just makes things messy.

What you probably want is something like this:

Register.cshtml file:

```
@model Models.RegisterViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     @Html.ValidationSummary(false)

    // Form Register here

}
<div>Or if you already have an account then login:</div>
@Html.RenderAction("Login")
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
         return PartialView();
    }
}
```

This will render the login view in the register view, you can also do this the other way around. Although I'd personally just offer a link to the user to redirect them to login page rather than using renderaction.

Comment: I'll try your suggest. Thanks for kind helping